# How do you split a string into word pairs?

Tags: php, regex, arrays, string

I am trying to split a string into an array of word pairs in PHP. So for example if you have the input string:

```
"split this string into word pairs please"
```

the output array should look like

```
Array (
    [0] => split this
    [1] => this string
    [2] => string into
    [3] => into word
    [4] => word pairs
    [5] => pairs please
    [6] => please
)
```

some failed attempts include:

```
$array = preg_split('/\w+\s+\w+/', $string);
```

which gives me an empty array, and

```
preg_match('/\w+\s+\w+/', $string, $array);
```

which splits the string into word pairs but doesn't repeat the word. Is there an easy way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: regex isn't always the answer to "strings"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why not just use explode ?

```
$str = "split this string into word pairs please";

$arr = explode(' ',$str);
$result = array();
for($i=0;$i<count($arr)-1;$i++) {
        $result[] =  $arr[$i].' '.$arr[$i+1];
}
$result[] =  $arr[$i];
```

[**Working link**](http://www.ideone.com/GZ96I)

Comment: how about `split    this,  string` ?

Comment: @stereofrog, perhaps `preg_split()` to split on `\W` or similar

Comment: I added `if ((count($arr) % 2) != 0) { $result[] = $arr[count($arr) - 1]; }` after the for loop in your solution to grab the last word and it worked great, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to repeat with a regular expression, you'll need some sort of look-ahead or look-behind. Otherwise, the expression will not match the same word multiple times:

```
$s = "split this string into word pairs please";
preg_match_all('/(\w+) (?=(\w+))/', $s, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
$a = array_map(
  function($a)
  {
    return $a[1].' '.$a[2];
  },
  $matches
);
var_dump($a);
```

Output:

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "split this"
  [1]=>
  string(11) "this string"
  [2]=>
  string(11) "string into"
  [3]=>
  string(9) "into word"
  [4]=>
  string(10) "word pairs"
  [5]=>
  string(12) "pairs please"
}
```

Note that it does not repeat the last word "please" as you requested, although I'm not sure why you would want that behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You could `explode` the string and then loop through it:

```
$str = "split this string into word pairs please";
$strSplit = explode(' ', $str);
$final = array();    

for($i=0, $j=0; $i<count($strSplit); $i++, $j++)
{
    $final[$j] = $strSplit[$i] . ' ' . $strSplit[$i+1];
}
```

I think this works, but there should be a way easier solution.

**Edited to make it conform to OP's spec.** - as per codaddict

Comment: your output does not match OP's requirement.

Comment: Wow, your right codaddict, and I was actually thinking your answer was wrong, ironically.

Comment: The use of `$j` is completely redundant.

Answer (score 1):

```
$s = "split this string into word pairs please";

$b1 = $b2 = explode(' ', $s);
array_shift($b2);
$r = array_map(function($a, $b) { return "$a $b"; }, $b1, $b2);

print_r($r);
```

gives:

```
Array
(
    [0] => split this
    [1] => this string
    [2] => string into
    [3] => into word
    [4] => word pairs
    [5] => pairs please
    [6] => please
)
```